# Ionic 4 Angular NgIf binding

Tags: ionic4

sorry for my bad English, I would like to consult how to implement * ngIf in this case:

I have a string variable constructed like this:
varname = 'a = 1 && b = 2 && c = 3 && d = 0';
I want to filter a list with elements that have the 4 properties, a, b, c and d.

My question is ***how can I replace the condition inside the ngIf*** since it does NOT accept me * ngIf = "{{varname}}"

Thank you very much for the help you could give me

```
Ionic:

  ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.11.0 (C:\Users\Estelita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
  Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
  @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
  @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
  @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
  @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android)
   NodeJS            : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.12.1
   OS                : Windows 8.1
```

Comment: ngIf only cares about expression being true or false, you need such boolean property and perform boolean validation in your ts and outside  of the template code.

Answer (score 1):

*ngIf does not need the {{ }} brackets to evaluate component properties.

```
<ion-item *ngIf="varname">
   If varname is not null this sentence will be rendered.
</ion-item>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rich thanks for answering, what I intend to do is evaluate from the content of the variable. a = 1 && ... etc.

That is, I substitute the content of varname, which would be the "evaluation formula"
What I intend to do finally, is to evaluate "dynamically":
* ngIf = "a = 1 && b = 2 && ........"

Comment: I'm sorry I do not completely understand. I created an Angular [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhfqcc) where I tried to create a solution based on my understanding of the problem. Is it what you where thinking? Or maybe would it make sense to perform the evaluation and filtering in the component instead of within the *ngIf?

Comment: I will explain it better. I have a list of images of cities. I want to filter it by neighborhood, population, restaurants and hospitals.
4 independent variables, but attributes of each image.

When I choose the select, I take the chosen value OF EACH ONE and assemble a string like the one I explained.

Then, in the ngIf I want to make the substitution, that is, filter something like that

* ngIf = "hospital ==" a "&& ......

The problem is that it may not filter anything, or just one of the 4 variables. That is why I assemble the string before and don't put the 4 filters in the ngIf